# How do I use float or a similar css command with buttons inside a bootstrap4 form input group?

Tags: forms, bootstrap-4, css-float

I have two buttons inside a bootstrap form input group. I dont want the buttons touching so I have reduced their sizes and floated one left and the other right.

The sizes have been reduced, but for unknown reasons they are not floating.

The float works if I remove them from the input group, but then they no longer work with the form when they are click.

How do I use float or a similar css command with buttons inside a bootstrap4 form input group?

```
<div class="justify-content-center">
    <div class="input-group col-sm-6 mx-auto mb-2">
      <div class="input-group">
        <button id="wechat"  type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary mt-2 float-left disabled" style="width:49%;" name="method" value="wechat">WeChat</button>
        <button id="paypal" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary mt-2 float-right" style="width:49%;" name="method" value="paypal">PayPal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So in an ideal situation you would like one of the buttons to be on the left and one on the right? Or you just don't want the buttons to touch?

From reading your question it sounds like the main concern is just the buttons are touching in which case you could just add padding to the style. So...

```
<div class="justify-content-center">
    <div class="input-group col-sm-6 mx-auto mb-2">
      <div class="input-group">
        <button id="wechat"  type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary mt-2 float-left disabled" style="width:49%; padding:10px" name="method" value="wechat">WeChat</button>
        <button id="paypal" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary mt-2 float-right" style="width:49%; padding: 10px" name="method" value="paypal">PayPal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You can play around with how much padding you want and you can also try padding-right and padding-left. You might also want to try margin instead to fix the issue. This should fix the issue of the buttons touching. Trying to align them differently is going to be another issue because all of the content in the form is wrapped in `<div class="justify-content-center">`